# Delete bitbucket repository by cURL

Tags: git, curl, bitbucket, bitbucket-api

Anyone know how to delete repositories from bitbucket by cURL  ?

At the moment I've made script to create  remote repository on bitbucket by curl

```
#!/bin/bash
while read line
do
curl --user user:password https://api.bitbucket.org/1.0/repositories/ --data name=$line --data is_private=true --data owner=OWNER
done<repo_list.txt
```

but now I cant delete that repositories from bitbucket by curl

Im am using

```
curl -X DELETE --user user:password https://api.bitbucket.org/1.0/repositories/ --data name=$line --data is_private=true --data owner=OWNER
```

and have error {"error": {"message": "'username'", "detail": " File \"/opt/python/domains/bitbucket.org/current/bitbucket/local/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/piston/resource.py\", line 208, in call\n}

https://bitbucket.org/zhemao/bitbucket-cli delete repositories only from user account but dont have option to delete repository owned by other owner which I belongs to.

Any ideas ?

Comment: Thanks for help. This command work for me now: curl -X DELETE --user user:password https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/owner/repo_name

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The syntax for [deleting](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/repository+Resource+1.0#repositoryResource1.0-DELETEanexistingrepositoryRedDEPRECATED) a repo is different from the syntax for [creating](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/repository+Resource+1.0#repositoryResource1.0-POSTanewrepositoryRedDEPRECATED) a repo.

To create:

```
POST https://bitbucket.org/api/1.0/repositories --data "name=mynewrepo"
```

To delete:

```
DELETE https://bitbucket.org/api/1.0/repositories/{accountname}/{repo_slug}
```

Also, the API v1.0 methods are deprecated, so you should use the [v2.0 methods](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/repository+Resource).

To create:

```
POST https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/{owner}/{repo_slug}
```

To delete:

```
DELETE https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/{owner}/{repo_slug}
```